# how do I apply different images for each face in coin3d or openInventor?

Tags: image, openinventor, coin3d

I create 6 face by SoIndexedFaceSet and I want apply different images for each face by SoTexture3, But it doesn't work. Could you please give me some suggestions about how to apply different images or textures for each face in Coin3d or OpenIventor? I don't know if it's my method is wrong or I lost some other key property? Thank you so much. And Here is my code

````
    //
    SoSeparator* root = new SoSeparator;
    root->ref();
    //
    SoTransform* pTransfrom = new SoTransform;
    pTransfrom->translation.setValue(0, 0, 0);
    root->addChild(pTransfrom);
    SoMaterialBinding* faceBind = new SoMaterialBinding;
    faceBind->value = SoMaterialBinding::PER_PART;
    root->addChild(faceBind);
    //
    SoTexture3* texture = new SoTexture3;
    texture->filenames.set1Value(0, SbString("D:/wrapper/TCom_Wall_Stone3_2x2_1K_albedo.tif"));
    texture->filenames.set1Value(1, SbString("D:/wrapper/Com_Wall_Stone3_2x2_1K_ao.tif"));
    texture->filenames.set1Value(2, SbString("D:/wrapper/TCom_Wall_Stone3_2x2_1K_height.tif"));
    texture->filenames.set1Value(3, SbString("D:/wrapper/TCom_Wall_Stone3_2x2_1K_normal.tif"));
    texture->filenames.set1Value(4, SbString("D:/wrapper/4.jpg"));
    texture->filenames.set1Value(5, SbString("D:/wrapper/5.jpg"));
    root->addChild(texture);
    //
    SoCoordinate3* coordinates = new SoCoordinate3;
    //front
    coordinates->point.set1Value(0, 0, 0, 0);
    coordinates->point.set1Value(1, step, 0, 0);
    coordinates->point.set1Value(2, step, 0, step);
    coordinates->point.set1Value(3, 0, 0, step);
    //back
    coordinates->point.set1Value(4, step, step, 0);
    coordinates->point.set1Value(5, 0, step, 0);
    coordinates->point.set1Value(6, 0, step, step);
    coordinates->point.set1Value(7, step, step, step);
    //
    root->addChild(coordinates);
    //
    SoIndexedFaceSet* faceSet = new SoIndexedFaceSet;
    //front
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(0, 0);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(1, 1);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(2, 2);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(3, 3);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(4, -1);
    //back
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(5, 4);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(6, 5);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(7, 6);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(8, 7);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(9, -1);
    //left
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(10, 5);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(11, 0);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(12, 3);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(13, 6);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(14, -1);
    //right
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(15, 1);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(16, 4);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(17, 7);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(18, 2);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(19, -1);
    //top
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(20, 3);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(21, 2);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(22, 7);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(23, 6);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(24, -1);
    //bottom
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(25, 5);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(26, 4);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(27, 1);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(28, 0);
    faceSet->coordIndex.set1Value(29, -1);
    root->addChild(faceSet);
    //
    setSceneGraph(root);```
````

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you need to set texture coordinates, so Open Inventor knows how to access the images in the 3D texture node.
Below is a version that works.  Notes:

- Your 3D texture appears to be an array of 2D textures, not a "volume".
  So it's convenient to set the 'layout' field to ARRAY. This disables interpolation between layers.
- Note that you only need 8 vertices because they can be shared between faces, but you need 24 texture coordinates so that each face can have it's own image.
- In each texture coordinate, the third value specifies which layer of the 3D texture should be used (which image in the array). 0 is the first, 1 is the last.

Example code:

```
  // Tell Inventor there is a texture coordinate index for each vertex
  auto texCoordBinding = new SoTextureCoordinateBinding();
  texCoordBinding->value = SoTextureCoordinateBinding::Binding::PER_VERTEX_INDEXED;
  root->addChild(texCoordBinding);

  // Six textures stored as one 3D texture.
  // Layout = ARRAY tells Inventor to NOT interpolate between layers.
  auto texture = new SoTexture3;
  texture->filenames.set1Value(0, SbString("Data/Front.png"));
  texture->filenames.set1Value(1, SbString("Data/Back.png"));
  texture->filenames.set1Value(2, SbString("Data/Left.png"));
  texture->filenames.set1Value(3, SbString("Data/Right.png"));
  texture->filenames.set1Value(4, SbString("Data/Top.png"));
  texture->filenames.set1Value(5, SbString("Data/Bottom.png"));
  texture->layout = SoTexture3::Layout::ARRAY;
  root->addChild(texture);

  // Coordinates: 8 vertices because they can be shared between faces.
  // Texture Coordinates: The Z value tells Inventor which layer of the 3D
  //   texture to use as the texture image.
  float step = 1;
  SbVec3f vertices[] = {
    {0,0,0}, {step,0,0}, {step, 0, step}, {0,0,step},
    {step,step,0}, {0,step,0}, {0,step,step}, {step,step,step} };
  SbVec3f texCoords[] = {
    {0,0,0   }, {1,0,0   }, {1,1,0   }, {0,1,0   }, // front
    {0,0,0.2f}, {1,0,0.2f}, {1,1,0.2f}, {0,1,0.2f}, // back
    {0,0,0.4f}, {1,0,0.4f}, {1,1,0.4f}, {0,1,0.4f}, // left
    {0,0,0.6f}, {1,0,0.6f}, {1,1,0.6f}, {0,1,0.6f}, // right
    {0,0,0.8f}, {1,0,0.8f}, {1,1,0.8f}, {0,1,0.8f}, // top
    {0,0,1   }, {1,0,1   }, {1,1,1   }, {0,1,1   }  // bottom
  };
  auto vprop = new SoVertexProperty();
  vprop->vertex.setValues(0, sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(SbVec3f), vertices);
  vprop->texCoord3.setValues(0, sizeof(texCoords)/sizeof(SbVec3f), texCoords);

  // Shape
  auto faceSet = new SoIndexedFaceSet;
  int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, -1, // front
    4, 5, 6, 7, -1, // back
    5, 0, 3, 6, -1, // left
    1, 4, 7, 2, -1, // right
    3, 2, 7, 6, -1, // top
    5, 4, 1, 0, -1  // bottom
  };
  int texCoordIndices[] = {
     0,  1,  2,  3, // front
     4,  5,  6,  7, // back
     8,  9, 10, 11, // left
    12, 13, 14, 15, // right
    16, 17, 18, 19, // top
    20, 21, 22, 23  // bottom
  };
  faceSet->coordIndex.setValues(0, sizeof(indices)/sizeof(int), indices);
  faceSet->textureCoordIndex.setValues(0, sizeof(texCoordIndices)/sizeof(int), texCoordIndices);
  faceSet->vertexProperty = vprop;
  root->addChild(faceSet);
```

Comment: mike, Thank you so much for your help.  Could you please tell me which version of Coin3d do you using?  I haven't found layout property in SoTexture3 class. I get Coin3d code from github and build by myself.

Comment: I haven't found layout property in SoTexture3 class.  So it has a compile error in my side.                                        
texture->layout = SoTexture3::Layout::ARRAY;

Comment: I am using commercial Open Inventor, not Coin3D.
The solution should still work.  Just disable interpolation, so you don't get mixing of the images in the 3D stack.  In Open Inventor you would do this:

    texture->magFilter = SoTexture3::NEAREST;